# Is it safe to memcpy regex_t?

Tags: c, regex

Is a simple, shallow copy of `regex_t` (from POSIX [`<regex.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/regex.h.html) and [`regcomp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html) etc) guaranteed to always work?

Comment: Which `regex_t` are we talking about?

Answer (score 6):

> Is simple, shallow copy of `regex_t` guaranteed to always work?

Provided that the object pointed-to by the destination pointer is large enough to hold the bytes copied, and does not overlap the source object, there are no failure conditions defined for `memcpy()`.  To the extent that anything in a computer can be guaranteed, the copy is guaranteed to succeed.

However, that *does not* necessarily mean that the resulting copy can be used independently of the original.  POSIX does not place sufficient requirements on `regex_t` to ensure that, and it would not be too surprising if some implementations of `regex_t` contained pointers to dynamically-allocated data.  In fact, the existence of the `regfree()` function is an explicit provision for that possibility.

Comment: The mere existence of pointers to allocated data inside the object don't mean anything. If we call `regfree` on the copy, but not the original, we are okay. What is problematic is the potential sensitivity of the object to its own address: pointers aimed within itself, either within that object itself, or emanating from other objects (not even known to the application).

Comment: @Kaz, the existence of pointers to dynamically allocated data means that the copy cannot be used *independently of the original*, which is what I claimed.  Your stipulation that `regree()` not be called on the original if it is called on the copy is just such a dependency, and the most likely one, but not the only possible one.

Comment: @Kaz *"The mere existence of pointers to allocated data inside the object don't mean anything."* If those pointers are initialized when the object is created and never changed, then perhaps you're right. However if the implementation changes any of the pointers after the copy (e.g. with `realloc`, or an explicit `free` and `malloc`) then the copy of the object has an invalid pointer.

Comment: @user3386109 And that could happen in `regexec` if any aspects of the compilation are delayed to run time (e.g. NFA->DFA subset construction is done dynamically, with caching). The memory (re)allocation isn't necessarily all done when `regcomp` is done.

Answer (score 2):

The [POSIX spec here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regfree.html) is rather poorly written:

> If the preg argument to regexec() or regfree() is not a compiled regular expression returned by regcomp(), the result is undefined.

`preg` is not an object but a pointer to an object (so it should say something like "does not point to...") and `regcomp` doesn't "return" it (it modifies a pointed-to object), but the intent of "is" seems to be that it has to be the same object, not another object with the same value. I would interpret calling `regfree` on a copy as a violation of this, resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: I agree with this analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to interpret POSIX such that this is okay, but probably bold and unwise.

In ISO C (which is included inside POSIX by normative reference), the following is written about exactly one library type, and no other:

*"The address of the `FILE` object used to control a stream may be significant; a copy of a `FILE` object need not serve in place of the original."*

Essentially the same text is repeated in POSIX, **2.5 Standard I/O Streams.**

So you would think that this sets an "opt out" precedent: any representation that must not be copied will be documented with such a prohibition, and other types may be.

Furthermore, this is reinforced by the presence of explicit "opt out" in another area of the standard: threading:

*"For barriers, condition variables, mutexes, and read-write locks, [TSH] [Option Start]  if the process-shared attribute is set to PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE, [Option End]  only the synchronization object at the address used to initialize it can be used for performing synchronization."*

It does seem like the standard's approach is to spell out when the use of a copied object is prohibited.

Yet, I'd be wary of copying any structure that serves as some sort of stateful resource handle, rather than just an information structure (like `struct stat` or `struct pwent`). Implementors could accidentally make such a thing sensitive to its own address, with something like:

```
struct foo {
  type_t *internal_ptr;
  /* ... */
  type_t internal_array_of_something[...];
};
```

There isn't any text in POSIX which *prohibits* that. A similar issue arises if the system maintains, somewhere, back-pointers to the structure, or within the structure.

POSIX must be read, first and foremost, not as a guide for programming (what programs may or may not do) but as a set of requirements for an implementation which accepts programs.

It doesn't look like there is a requirement in POSIX which says that an implementation must not make a `regex_t` sensitive to its address. If so, that means that such an implementation doesn't fail to be conforming.

That is to say, that this issue is emphasized in the requirement areas for `FILE *` streams and `pthread` synchronization objects might not have any implications for any other areas.